# Leaky Custom Object for storing data from a plist

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have made a *very* simple custom object `pictureData`.

Here is the .h file

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface pictureData : NSObject {
    NSString    *fileName;
    NSString    *photographer;
    NSString    *title;
    NSString    *license;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString      *fileName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString      *photographer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString      *title;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString      *license;

+(pictureData*)picDataWith:(NSDictionary*)dictionary;

@end
```

The .m file

```
#import "pictureData.h"

@implementation pictureData

@synthesize fileName;
@synthesize photographer;
@synthesize title;
@synthesize license;

+ (pictureData*)picDataWith:(NSDictionary *)dictionary {

    pictureData *tmp = [[[pictureData alloc] init] autorelease];

    tmp.fileName = [dictionary objectForKey:@"fileName"];
    tmp.photographer = [dictionary objectForKey:@"photographer"];
    tmp.title = [dictionary objectForKey:@"title"];
    tmp.license = [dictionary objectForKey:@"license"];

    return tmp;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [fileName release];
    [photographer release];
    [title release];
    [license release];
}

@end
```

I then set up these objects in an array, like so:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pictureLicenses" ofType:@"plist"];

    NSArray *tmpDataSource = [NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    self.dataSource = tmp;
    [tmp release];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in tmpDataSource) {
        pictureData *pic = [pictureData picDataWith:dict];
        NSLog(@"%@", pic.title);
        [self.dataSource addObject:pic];
    }
```

Everything works smashingly. I have a table view which loads the proper picture images, and information, no problem. Upon running Instruments for leaks, I see that my `pictureData` object is leaks with every allocation.

I would assume that with having my object autoreleased I would not have to worry about manually allocating and deallocating them.

Perhaps is my issue that I use autorelease, which the autoReleasePool keeps a retain count of +1 and then when I add a `pictureData` object to my array, that also retains it? Thank you all for your time!

**edit: Don't forget to call super! Thank you Sam!**

Comment: From your code, everything looks fine except you are missing a call to `[super dealloc]` in your `dealloc` method.  Note that this should be the last line in your `dealloc` method.  Also, `self.dataSource` is increasing the retainCount on your `pictureData` objects.  I assume at some point you remove instances from this collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change dealloc to:

```
-(void)dealloc {
    [fileName release];
    [photographer release];
    [title release];
    [license release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

(call `[super dealloc]`)

Answer (score -1):

In your function, change the return value to include autorelease, like

```
+ (pictureData*)picDataWith:(NSDictionary *)dictionary 
{
    ...
    ...
    return [tmp autorelease];
}
```

When you add pictureData object to dataSource, you increase the retain count, so you should autorelease it while returning.

Hope it helps.

Comment: He's already got an autorelease in there.  If you add another one the app will likely crash.